# How to connect to firefox instance with debugger port?

Tags: selenium, debugging, firefox, webdriver

I am trying to do remote debugging on a Firefox instance similarly to how I would do it in Chrome:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

If I start Chrome with this parameter, I can then inspect pages from another Chrome instance by navigating to localhost:9222

I am trying to do the same with Firefox:

1. Set "enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" and "enable remote debugging" options to true
2. opened firefox with the following parameter:

   "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -start-debugger-server 1234

Despite this, when I navigate to localhost:1234, the following happens:

- I get multiple popups, that tell me there is an incoming request to Firefox
- Even when I click okay, nothing seems to happen
- localhost:1234 gives "refused to connect" error

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: hi! sadly no, so we eventually abandoned this idea and went in another direction

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has more debug functionality than chrome/chromium and to access those you need to:

Goto about:debugging 
( Can be found in GUI under: triple-bar Button[≡] > Web Developer > Remote Debugging )

Enter your host Network Location and click Add

Click on your debugging instance on the right side.

Debug whatever you wanna debug(Tabs, Extensions or Processes etc.)